# Android exclude WiFis

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, wifi-hotspot

In my area I have a lot of paid WiFi hotspots that are open and my android connects to them automatically.

Can I set that WiFi's only with certain keyword in their name(SSID) would not connect to?

EDIT:
Imagine there several hundred hotspots of open wi-fi hotspots on diferent networks configurations and so on. The only common denominator is that all of the have network name in ssid. Lets say 'crazy sheep'

On a flip side same area has hundreds of free open wi-fi hotspots again all in different networks and these have almost no common denominator.

In the past I have done some Android development. So I do not look for settings tutorial. If the function is in stock there is a little chance I will not know about it.

**I am looking for**

*An app that adds an option to write a query (regex is fine) with SSID as a variable in it. That would omit matching networks from initiating connection but would not affect other networks*

Answer (score 0):

Tap on those wifi ssid names and and use forget network to remove phone from automatically connecting to the network

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rajat's answer ("Forget" each network), when you connect to a new network or re-connect to a network you're device has "forgotten", you have the choice to clear the "Connect Automatically..." checkbox. If you do that, when you choose that connection, it will ask for the SSID each time.